# Problems with MySQL and PHP on Mac Server

Tags: php, mysql, macos

I use a Mac Server (Server 3.0) with the built in web server. I had to install MySQL after setting everything up as it is no longer included.....

I originally had issues with the Sock files and this was resolved. When I restarted the server I now get the error below from PHP yet I am still able to connect from MySQL workbench.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)"}}

I don't usually use root but no accounts are working.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) is a MySQL connection error. Usually implies invalid user and/or password. Just check this once again.

Comment: Also just check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html

Comment: I have checked, and all of that is fine, I can connect through mysql workbench but not PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-installed MySQL and Reimported databases and everything is working again with new MySQL users I create but the old ones still don't work.